# Dot product in three dimenions

Tags: vectors

I know how to prove that that to get the dot product of two vectors (in 2-D space) you can either simply add the products of their parallel components, or multiply their magnitudes to the cosine between both vectors. Namely, I can prove these two ways of doing the dot-product are equivalent.

But how do I prove this is true in 3-D?

The way I prove this in 2-D is basically shown here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DotProduct.html

Comment: Part of my answer here shows how to do it from the law of cosines.


 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874445/the-inner-product-determines-the-structure-of-the-space/874457#874457

Comment: I can't believe I read this after so long. Thanks so much. If you like you'd like you could just copy the first part of your paragraph on that post and I'd accept it as an answer to this Q.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it would be to show that, if $U$ is a unitary matrix, then $\langle Ux, Uy \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$.  Indeed, if $\vec u$, $\vec v$, and $\vec w$ are mutually perpendicular vectors of length 1 which form the columns of such a matrix, then
\begin{align*}
\langle Ux, Uy \rangle &= \langle x_1 \vec u + x_2 \vec v + x_3 \vec w, y_1 \vec u + y_2 \vec v + y_3 \vec w \rangle\\
\end{align*}
which will simplify to $\langle x,y\rangle$ using the bilinearity properties of the inner product.  This helps because you can use a unitary matrix to send any pair of vectors into the $xy$-plane, where the inner product corresponds directly to a two-dimensional inner product, and the angle between the vectors does not change.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to handle matrices yet. Do you think that if I do a quick research I can understand what is said here?